# How to convert json data type from integer to string from table using mysql

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.3

My table contain thousand of rows and one of my column data in json format.I need to change json value integer to string.

For example: `{"1":123}` will changed to `{"1":"123"}`.

I have tried with below query.

```
UPDATE table
SET details = JSON_SET(details, '$."1"', CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(details, '$."1"')) AS CHAR))
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(details, '$."1"')) IS NOT NULL;
```

But i got this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '))
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(details, '$."1"')) IS NOT NULL' at line 2
```

Comment: Can you try this and check if it works out: 
UPDATE your_table_name
SET details = JSON_SET(details, '$."1"', CONVERT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(details, '$."1"')), CHAR))
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(details, '$."1"')) IS NOT NULL;

Comment: Your query working fine https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bNLRY8xi4y73iXmRGTM3s4/0 ! which version of mysql you are using ?

Comment: Server version: 10.3.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET details = JSON_SET(
    details, 
    '$."1"', 
    CAST(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(details, '$."1"')) AS CHAR)
)
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(details, '$."1"')) IS NOT NULL;
```

The above query will update the details column in your table, converting the integer value within the JSON object to a string where it's not null.

[Check Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ws5lLDlP) for example.